# About CURL Request

Tags: android, json, curl

I have to use CURL request to parse an API link using android application.In the response i get an id and username as output.But,I have to display a token value from that API.That token is displayed on Linux machine while running curl.I didn't get the token value in windows machine.I used the code like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://moneyplayer.herokuapp.com/users.json");
  JSONObject json_one,json;

   json_one = new JSONObject();
   json =new JSONObject();                  

    json.put("password","userPwd");
    json.put("username","userEmail");
    json_one.put("user",json);
    Log.v("JSON Response is",""+json_one);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json_one.toString());
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httppost.setEntity(se);             
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
       // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);       
    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.v("Response String Value is",""+responseStr);
```

In Linux machine the output is displayed like this:

```
{"id":37,"username":"testing123@1234.com"}
HTTP/1.1 200 O4 Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate 
Content-Type:application /json;
charset=utf-8 Date: Mon, 17 Mar 2014 15:33:51 GMT 
Etag:"a8979713bed4432cb624cb404df16a53"
Set-Cookie:
remember_token=BAhbCGkqSSIlMTZkYmE4ZDhhZTA2YzI2OWQwZjM2Y2ZjZjNmY2YyZGUGOgZFRjA%3D--d29db574adf7a4df8671eb75f43166101b81ef65; path=/; expires=Fri, 17-Mar-2034 15:33:51 GMT
Set-Cookie:
_live_local_web_session=BAh7B0kiCmZsYXNoBjoGRVRvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7BjoOc3VjY2Vzc2VzVDoMQGNsb3NlZEY6DUBmbGFzaGVzewY7ClsGSSIiU3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5IGNyZWF0ZWQgcHJvZmlsZS4GOwBUOglAbm93bzokQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOj
```

Comment: Can you show what was displayed on the linux machine?

Comment: I displayed the Linux machine output details below the code.